# ¿Como nombrar ALIAS SQL en PHP?

Tags: php

El problema me radica cuando quiero llamar por nombre de "alias+columna" desde PHP.

```
   $sqlPersonaje = 'SELECT p.nombre,
                           p.nivel,
                           p.fuerza,
                           p.destreza,
                           p.vitalidad,
                           p.inteligencia,
                           p.agilidad,
                           p.suerte,
                           cl.nombre
                           FROM personaje p
                           INNER JOIN clase cl ON cl.ID_Clase = p.ID_Clase';

$respuestaPersonaje = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlPersonaje);
$personaje = mysqli_fetch_assoc($respuestaPersonaje);
mysqli_close($conn);

<li>Nombre: <span id="nombre"><?php echo $personaje['nombre'];?></span></li>
<li>Clase: <span id="clase"><?php echo $personaje['nombre']; ?></span></li>
```

Si le coloco a el nombre de personaje "$personaje['p.nombre']" me devuelve un error, si le coloco "$personaje['nombre']" me devuelve el nombre de la clase a la que pertenece (Note que me devuelve el ultimo campo con igual nombre).

Les paso el error que me devuelve, pero dudo que sirva de algo, ya que el resto de valores me los devuelve de manera perfecta,me gustaría saber como ser mas exacto a la hora de definir lo que quiero que me devuelva PHP:

**Notice: Undefined index: p.nombre in B:\xampp\htdocs\Juego\app\module\juego\personaje.php on line 29**

Si alguno sabe como hacer en estos casos le agradecería demasiado.
Espero halla sido clara la pregunta.

Borre la publicación anterior ya que me había equivocado en la consulta, disculpas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para eliminar la ambiguidad con las columnas `nombre` en tu consulta, les puedes asignar un alias usando la claúsula `AS` de la siguiente manera:

```sql
SELECT p.nombre AS personaje_nombre,
       p.nivel,
       p.fuerza,
       p.destreza,
       p.vitalidad,
       p.inteligencia,
       p.agilidad,
       p.suerte,
       cl.nombre AS clase_nombre
       FROM personaje p
       INNER JOIN clase cl ON cl.ID_Clase = p.ID_Clase
```

Ahora puedes recuperar ambos nombres sin confusión usando `personaje_nombre` y `clase_nombre` respectivamente.

Comment: Perfecto! Acabo de probarlo y funciona correctamente. Muy rapida la respuesta. Apenas pasen los minutos necesarios cierro la pregunta :)

Comment: Ya puedo dar puntos así que te los merecías.. Gracias por la ayuda denuevo.

Answer (score -1):

UTILIZA EL AS PARA DIFERENCIAR NOMBRE DE COLUMNAS
Y AL IMPRIMIRLAS SIEMPRE ES EN MAYUSCULAS PORQUE LOS TITULOS DE LAS COLUMNAS EN SQL SIEMPRE ES EN MAYUSCULA

$sqlPersonaje = 'SELECT p.nombre AS PNOMBRE,
                           p.nivel,
                           p.fuerza,
                           p.destreza,
                           p.vitalidad,
                           p.inteligencia,
                           p.agilidad,
                           p.suerte,
                           cl.nombre
                           FROM personaje p
                           INNER JOIN clase cl ON cl.ID_Clase = p.ID_Clase';

$respuestaPersonaje = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlPersonaje);
$personaje = mysqli_fetch_assoc($respuestaPersonaje);
mysqli_close($conn);

Nombre:

Clase:

Comment: Sospecho que te gustan las mayúsculas :)

Comment: no es que tenia bloqueado mayusculas en el pinche teclado ja ja ja :)

Comment: Muchas gracias Jose! Ya quedo solucionado .. :) saludos...